# Python pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object

I have a pandas dataframe with approx. 20 columns and I want to print out the values of only 4 columns to a csv file.

My python code is:

```
df(['statnr','agldate','stdragl','ff_pred']).to_csv("out.csv", sep=';')
```

I get this error message:
**TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

What am i doing wrong? Any hint is appreciated!

Thanks and kind regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong brackets.

```py
df[['statnr','agldate','stdragl','ff_pred']].to_csv("out.csv", sep=';')
```

will do what you want. Round brackets, when following a character are reserved for function calls such as `to_csv()`. Therefore, Python is trying to call your dataframe as if it were a function, obviously producing an error

Answer (score 0):

You should,

1. To **PRINT**,

```py
print(df[['statnr','agldate','stdragl','ff_pred']].to_string())
```

2. To **csv** file,

```py
df[['statnr','agldate','stdragl','ff_pred']].to_csv("out.csv", sep=';')
```